# Read Java Object that leads to TemplateException in Freemarker template engine

Tags: java, freemarker

I am writing a Java Utility to generate output files using freemarker template. I have a List of objects that I write into a file using freemarker. E.g. My java object is an employee having fName, lName and age. I am using following code snippet to generate the output file:

```
<#list employees as e>
Fname: ${e.fName} Lname: ${e.lName} Age: ${e.age}
</#list>
```

Now, I am using a custom template exception handler that handle exceptions in case fName, lName OR age is missing from the employee object.

```
configuration.setTemplateExceptionHandler(new FreemarkerExceptionHandler());
```

I want to read the employee object that is throwing the exception in the FreemarkerExceptionHandler class,  but am unable to read it. I am using the following code to read the list of employees, but am getting all the employees, rather than one specific employee that lead to this error.

```
TemplateHashModel templateHashModel = environment.getDataModel();

TemplateModel templateModel = templateHashModel.get("employees");
List<Employee> emps = simpleSequence.toList();
```

Can anyone please confirm if this is feasible in freemarker to catch the object that lead to exception.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to do that as far as I see. My idea is extending `DefaultObjectWrapper` (assuming you are using that - see `Configuration.getObjectWrapper`), so when the subvariable (like `fNameo`) is get via `TemplateHashModel.get(String)`, you can catch any exceptions throw by `super.get(String)` in your override of `TemplateHashModel.get`, and then throw your own `TemplateException` subclass instance, into which you put the parent object in a field you have added for that. (And also you probably want to add the original exception as the cause exception of your exception.)