# Assign freemarker variable in template file and read the Variable in FreemarkerExceptionHandler

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a use case in which if exceptions are thrown while parsing a list of objects in freemarker template, I need to read the object value in `Exception Handler` class.

I am able to set the variable in freemarker template, by catching the exception in `<#attempt>` and `<#recover>` block and then assigning the value to a variable using `<#assign failedData="xx">` tag. 
Is it possible to read variable `failedData` in `Exception Handler` class ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the static `Environment.getCurrentEnvironment()` method to get the `Environment` object, and then use its methods to get template language variables. Although adding that information on `ObjectWrapper`-level is possibly a more correct solution (see [this answer to this earlier question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57789211/read-java-object-that-leads-to-templateexception-in-freemarker-template-engine/)).